I am using Ubuntu 24.04, and my microphone is not being detected. I’ve tried multiple troubleshooting steps but haven’t had any success yet
Here's what I tried:

Checked the microphone in ALSA Mixer (Realtek ALC285, HDA Intel PCH) – Mic Boost levels are visible, but there’s no input detection.

Used the arecord -l command, and it correctly lists the capture device (Realtek ALC285 Analog).

Ran pactl list short sources which shows PipeWire is running, but the microphone is in a suspended state.

Tried restarting PulseAudio and reloading ALSA modules using the following commands:
 pulseaudio -k  
 pulseaudio --start  
 sudo alsa force-reload  


Attempted to enable WirePlumber, but encountered an error.

Checked the Sound Settings in Ubuntu, and no input devices are listed, though the output works fine.


Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
